# "Cannot find any instance of Webots"

Tags: ros, ros2, roslaunch, ros-humble, webots

you guys are my last straw :)

I just started using ROS2 together with Webots. I downloaded ros-humble-webots-ros2 and Webots2023b and launched my scipt with

```
ros2 launch vacusim_robot_driver simple_arena_launch.py.
```

Webots starts normally, but in the Webots Terminal i get this:

```
INFO: 'Custom_iRobot_Create' extern controller: Waiting for local or remote connection on port 1234 targeting robot named 'Custom_iRobot_Create'.
INFO: 'Custom_iRobot_Create' extern controller: connected.
INFO: 'Custom_iRobot_Create' extern controller: refusing connection attempt from another extern controller.
INFO: 'Custom_iRobot_Create' extern controller: disconnected, waiting for new connection.
```

If I look in my Ubuntu Terminal i get this:

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/name/.ros/log/2024-03-19-18-32-52-532359-name-HP-Spectre-x360-Convertible-13-ae0xx-21546
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
WARNING: No valid Webots directory specified in `ROS2_WEBOTS_HOME` and `WEBOTS_HOME`, fallback to default installation folder /home/name/.ros/webotsR2023b/webots.
[INFO] [webots-1]: process started with pid [21547]
[INFO] [driver-2]: process started with pid [21549]
[driver-2] Cannot find any instance of Webots, retrying for another 50 seconds...
[driver-2] [WARN] [1710869576.642505189] [Custom_iRobot_Create]: Passing robot description as a string is deprecated. Provide the URDF or Xacro file path instead.
[ERROR] [driver-2]: process has died [pid 21549, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/webots_ros2_driver/driver --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_0b0i1f1f'].
```

I searched for hours on the internet and just cant get behind the mistake I made, thats why I decided to ask the pros :) Maybe somebody can help me.

Comment: As a sanity check: Have you checked the env vars with `echo $ROS2_WEBOTS_HOME` and `echo $WEBOTS_HOME`, and the contents of those directories? Where are your webots actually stored? Do these locations match?

Comment: As I understood it you dont really need it. If you dont calibrate these directories it will just use the standard directory. I think it connects to the controller but somehow disconnects after :(